# Traveling to Vietnam in HCMC Unlocked Phone/Sim Question

Tags: cellphones, vietnam

Would like to communicate while there for 2 weeks AND take quality pictures w/o breaking bank.

What should I use?  SimCards?  I currently have ATT.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking -- you want to know what sort of phone to buy? Or what SIM? Or where to buy? Can you edit your question to be a bit clearer, also you may want to give an indication of what would be too much money.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to check to make sure your phone will work overseas.  The USA uses different frequencies for voice calls than Asia, but the phones they market as "tri-band", "quad-band" or "international" will work outside the states.  Many of the newer smart phones and phablets already cover the full spectrum, but check to be sure.

Then pick up a pre-paid SIM with a data package when you arrive in HCMC. Data roaming on ATT will be expensive. I am not up to date on the best packages currently offered, perhaps someone else will jump in with specific company recommendations.